# Jenkins job getting stuck on execution of docker image as the agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have installed Jenkins and Docker inside a VM. I am using Jenkins pipeline project and my jenkins declarative pipeline looks like this.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello Nodejs'
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is a very basic pipeline following this link https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

When I try to build my jenkins job, it prints `Hello Nodejs`, but gets stuck at the next instruction i.e. execution of shell command. After 5 minutes, the job fails with this error

```
process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProject@tmp/durable-c118923c
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
```

I am not understanding why it is not executing the sh command.

[image: This is the screenshot of console output]

If I make it as `agent any`, it executes the `sh` command.

Comment: Please see my reply in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346984/jenkins-pipeline-error-process-apparently-never-started-in/58625316#58625316

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that it will help but I remember that node image is launched under root account by default. Jenkins uses its own ID when launching a container. So, probably, it's a permissions issue. Try to add **-u 0** argument:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'node:7-alpine'
        args '-u 0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Agent was running a container with a remote Docker host. To solve it, the Agent Home volume (i.e. `agent-home`) should be shared to the Docker Host. For example:

```yaml
services:
  agent:
    container_name: jenkins-agent
    . . .
    volumes:
      - agent-home:/home/jenkins/agent:rw
      . . .
  docker:
    container_name: jenkins-docker
    image: docker:25
    . . .
    volumes:
      - agent-home:/home/jenkins/agent:rw 
      . . .
    networks:
      agents:
        aliases:
          - docker
volumes:
  agent-home:
    name: jenkins-agent-home-dind
. . .
```

See also: https://blog.codefarm.me/2024/01/26/distributed-builds-architecture-on-jenkins/#configuring-agents-running-docker-in-docker