# Stuck in 'sh' stage and then Process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The "mvn clean" stage is getting stuck for sometime and lead to the following error:

```
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/<MyProject>@tmp/durable-8e4de4ec
(running Jenkins temporarily with -D 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem 
clearer)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is my jenkinsfile script:

```
pipeline{
agent{
    label 'DOCKER'
}
tools { 
    maven 'M3' 
    jdk 'JAVA_HOME' 
}
stages{
    stage('build'){
        steps{
            echo 'Running Build Phase'
            sh 'mvn clean'
        }
    }
}
}
```

Not sure if I need to update any configurations. I have updated /etc/init.d/jenkins with updated open-jdk version.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I am facing a similar issue. Did you find anything on this?

Comment: Hi @RanaRanvijaySingh, I am not sure what exactly made it work. I followed few posts e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346984/jenkins-pipeline-error-process-apparently-never-started-in and tweaked lot of with jenkins and docker config. Though, I did not update any dependencies in the code. Its the issue with config.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got my issue resolved. It was because of environment variables. This might help someone else. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987005/jenkins-does-not-recognize-command-sh/59852718#59852718

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found that if you go Manage Jenkins -> Configure System there will be an empty environment variable in the Global Properties section. Just delete that variable and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following argument to your jenkins java runtime to get more diagnostic info on why the "sh" steps fails:

```
-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true
```

---

If using with the kubernetes plugin, it may be the issue described [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-pipeline-sh-step-hangs-when-multiple-containers-are-used) (in the section *Pipeline sh step hangs when multiple containers are used*).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I run jenkins through docker container and I added `-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true` as environment variable when I run docker container: `docker run -u 0 --privileged --name jenkins -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true" jenkins/jenkins:latest`.
Now you should be able to see what is wrong when building a pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, my project had a bad name (thus a bad directory name).
My project was called "Site's updates" and the ' obviously broke the directory naming. Jenkins was not able to access the directory.

Hope this helps anyone.