Using Podman containers in Jenkins pipeline
Right now I have my Jenkins pipeline with docker containers. It has something like this:
docker.image(image_name).inside(container_params) {
  // this code is executed inside docker container 
}

I move from docker to podman and would like to use something similar in my jenkinsfile.
I have tried to install podman-docker package on my agent host, did some adjustments to subuid and subgid and got it almost running with Jenkins docker plugin. There is an exception complaining about insufficient docker version (which is actually podman).
I will try to workaround it moving from rhel 7 to rhel 9 to get a higher Podman version. But maybe there is a better solution how to migrate Jenkins pipeline from docker to podman containers.
Update:
I tried it on alma 9 with podman version 4.9.4-rhel. It can start a container, but fails to run a command inside of it.
docker.image(image_name).inside(container_params) {
  sh(returnStdout: true, script:'echo test')
}

returns
process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/workspace/myjob@tmp/durable-efee3a5c
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)


I found this helpful https://github.com/ibm-cloud-architecture/refarch-cloudnative-devops-kubernetes/blob/master/docs/podman.md

As I can see it is based on Jenkins Kubernetes plugin and requires running Kubernetes which I would like to avoid.

You can avoid it until you can’t :). Running a bunch of containers on a single host is just not efficient from the resource utilization perspective. You end up sizing that instance for the peak load and waste all that capacity when demand is low. And typical CI load is “spiky”

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346984/how-to-fix-process-apparently-never-started-in-error-in-jenkins-pipeline
